# unable to record any login details even though web addin plugin is selected in QTP

Tags: qtp

I am unable to record any login details even though web addin plugin is selected in QTP. my record is recording like a window recorder instead of browser

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the version of QTP you're using supports the version of the browser and that the browser extension is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether you opened QTP first .

Ifyou are suing QTP then you need to require a bunch of patches to get the workdone in windows 7